# The idea of scattering cross-section in classical mechanics, quantum mechanics, and high energy physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, particle-physics, definition, scattering-cross-section

I am very confused about the idea of the [cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_(physics)) in classical mechanics, quantum mechanics, and high energy physics. It seems like in classical and quantum mechanics, scattering cross-section is often in terms of some geometric parameters (for example the impact parameter in case of classical scattering), and if I am correct, the cross-section has the dimension of area.

However, in high energy physics, the cross-section is used to describe probability of certain interactions happening in a collision.

So, given the cross-section obtained from let's say Born's approximation, how does it relate to the probabilistic idea of the cross-section in high energy?

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing cross-section (which does have the unit's of area) with differential cross-section which has different units and is often called cross-section?

Comment: @LewisMiller, very likely, I am very new to the concept.

Comment: What gave you the impression that the cross section in HEP is somehow different than classical or quantum mechanics? It is an effective area intercepting your beam. The luminosity times the cross section amounts to the event rate, no? See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/crosec.html).